# How to debug nuxt-apollo server-side graphql requests

Tags: vue-apollo, nuxtjs

I'm trying to log nuxt-apollo's requests (headers and response), similar to the chrome devtools network tab, but then server-side. How can I do that with the nuxt-apollo module? I'm running nuxt universal mode. I want to do all graphql calls server-side.

Comment: hi, did you find the solution? I am facing the same problem

Comment: Try the node js debugger. Start your nuxt server with —inspect https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

did you try this google extension?

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apollo-client-developer-t/jdkknkkbebbapilgoeccciglkfbmbnfm

for me its the easiest wat to debug graphql request/mutations

Comment: Thanks for your help, the problem is that the apollo client is run on the nuxt-server, not in the browser like the normal apollo client. So that's why the chrome extension won't work to debug / log nuxt-server (acting as an apollo-client) requests, since it's not in the browser. My problem is basically, to debug nuxt-server <--> graphql server requests.

Answer (score 0):

I recommended you to check your apollo api in SPA mode after you make sure that is true change to UNIVERSAL!

Because in universal mode you see the result of api in html or js file